# Pivot Using 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot

First time posting here.  I have a table that I'd like to pivot the `TEST_NAME` so that they appear on a single row for each `SAMPLE_NUMBER`.  Example data from the table would look like this:

```
SAMPLE_NUMBER    TEST_NAME     TESTING_ORDER
12345            KF             1
12345            TAN            2
12345            V40            3
67890            S              1
67890            V100           2
67890            FTIR           3
```

I'd like my query to output:

```
12345  KF  TAN  V40
67890  S  V100  FTIR
```

but my query is giving me this output:

```
12345  <null>  <null>  <null>
67890  <null>  <null>  <null>
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT 
      SAMPLE_NUMBER, 
      TEST_NAME, 
      TESTING_ORDER 
FROM TEST where SAMPLE_NUMBER in (12345, 67890)
)src
PIVOT
(
MAX(ORDER_NUMBER) 
FOR ANALYSIS IN (1, 2, 3)
)pvt
```

Any tips/advice?  I've read many posts on this site and the help that's been given to others has been amazing. This is a great community!

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  MySQL and SQL Server are quite different.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT SAMPLE_NUMBER, [1], [2], [3]
FROM (SELECT SAMPLE_NUMBER, TEST_NAME, TESTING_ORDER 
      FROM TEST 
      WHERE SAMPLE_NUMBER in (12345, 67890)
     ) src
PIVOT (MAX(TEST_NAME) FOR TESTING_ORDER IN (1, 2, 3) ) pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using conditional aggregation or Crosstab:

```
SELECT
    Sample_Number,
    [1] = MAX(CASE WHEN Testing_Order = 1 THEN Test_Name END),
    [2] = MAX(CASE WHEN Testing_Order = 2 THEN Test_Name END),
    [3] = MAX(CASE WHEN Testing_Order = 3 THEN Test_Name END)
FROM Test
GROUP BY Sample_Number
```

---

For comparisons between the two methods: `PIVOT` and `Crosstab`, see this **[ARTICLE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/)**.